# What is the squiggly trace on this power rail?

Tags: pcb, dc, identification

The image below is a D.C. power rail from an IDE ZIF connector inputting to various components (my crude diagram displays the connections).

```
    component power inputs connect in between
                      ||   
VCC => squiggly trace => various capacitors => GND
```

I assume the caps are decoupling capacitors (from what I've read), but I don't know what the trace is there for. I measured a resistance of 2 ohms, so it surely isn't intended as a resistor. I looked at other answers mentioning serpentine traces, but this is a power rail, so why would that be necessary?

If any of you know what this could be for, I would appreciate any answers given.

Cheers

[image: The trace itself]

Comment: That looks almost like a membrane pushbutton contact point which doesn't make to much sense for its location and the fact it has a mask. It could be a capacitor but that doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: What is an "IDE ZIF"? Does that connector power this board, or does this board provide power to that connector? My assumption is that the capacitors are so far away for a reason and the narrow squiggly trace provides some inductance and resistance to limit some hot-plugging inrush effects.

Comment: Maybe a microstrip notch filter to deal with ringing?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany at that size, that would be pretty high frequency, and then the position and solder mask doesn't make too much sense, right?

Comment: @Justme The PCB is part of a PATA drive connected by a ZIF connector, so the power is coming from the connector. It does not support hot-swapping though, so not sure what it could be. Also there are a bunch more caps at different intervals on the same track, not just the ones pictured. Thanks for the info though

Comment: Looks like a PCB trace capacitor or interdigital capacitor, but those are more RF/microwave.